# Google Android ML Kit giving only category during Object detection

Tags: android, object-detection, google-mlkit

I am using android ML kit for Object detection. But it is always giving only the category of the object but never the actual object name. Can some one help me?
Following is my code

```
objectDetector.process(image)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(
                            new OnSuccessListener<List<DetectedObject>>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(List<DetectedObject> detectedObjects) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hello Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hello Length: " + detectedObjects.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    for (DetectedObject detectedObject : detectedObjects) {
                                        Rect boundingBox = detectedObject.getBoundingBox();
                                        Integer trackingId = detectedObject.getTrackingId();
                                        for (DetectedObject.Label label : detectedObject.getLabels()) {
                                            String text = label.getText();
                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hello: " + text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            })
```

Answer (score 1):

ML Kit's default Object Detection only provides coarse classification as you mentioned. You can use custom image classification models to provider fine-grained object classification. Please check out the documentation here:

https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/object-detection/custom-models/android

You can get custom image classification models on TensorFlow Hub:

https://tfhub.dev/ml-kit/collections/image-classification/1

One of such models you can use is:

https://tfhub.dev/google/lite-model/object_detection/mobile_object_labeler_v1/1